# Imagemagick command line, combine two different sized images

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I'd like to use "convert" (or whatever) from Imagemagick to combine two different sized images. I'd like them to be aligned at the bottom left corners. For example, I have two images:

trans_alpha.png (a transparent 42x37 blank image)
and shadow.png (a 68x23 image, which I want overlaid on trans_alpha.png aligned at the bottom left)

The result I'd like would be a 68x37 image, *NOTE* these sizes are examples only, I don't want to put the size into the command line, I just want to use the sizes from the input images.

I have tried a lot of combinations without success:

Attempt no. 776 (close, but aligned to top left, not bottom left)..:

```
convert trans_alpha.png -background none shadow.png -gravity SouthWest -layers merge  +repage result.png
```

Attempt no. 841 (aligned correctly, but result image isn't wide enough)...

```
convert trans_alpha.png shadow.png -gravity SouthWest -composite result.png
```

Hopefully that makes sense.
Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to my own question (courtesy of the clever people on [www.imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21164))

```
convert \
  trans_alpha.png shadow.png \
 -flip \
 -background none \
 -mosaic \
 -flip \
  result.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagemagick includes many useful transformations, but occasionally still it lacks the one you need.  Since your original images are PNG lossless bitmaps, you can convert both to long-form PBM or a related format like long-form PPM.  The advantage of these forms is that they represent the entire image, pixel by pixel, in plain text, which one can write a program -- usually a fairly short program -- to process any way one likes.  As storage formats, PBM and PPM are egregiously inefficient, but they are likewise egregiously easy to manipulate, and that's what you want.

The pbm(5) manpage (available for example on Debian/Ubuntu systems in the `netpbm` package) is well written and explains the process clearly.

Comment: Thanks, interesting alternative, but (ideally) I'd like an Imagemagick based solution rather than having to write a script/program to do what I want. Of course, failing that I'll look into PBM, it's a useful idea for many things, thanks again.

Comment: convert trans_alpha.png shadow.png -flip -background none -mosaic -flip result.png

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test at the moment but you can use `-page` with layers so something like this might work but you may need to calculate the Y offset:

```
convert \
   trans_alpha.png \
  -background none \
   shadow.png \
  -page +0+10 \
  -layers merge \
  +repage \
   result.png
```

You may not need the -background none

Comment: Thanks @Bonzo, I have tried that (with/without "-background none") but the offset doesn't seem to make a difference regardless of what value I give it (I was trying "-0-0" before) - always the same end result.

Comment: you need to put -page before "shadow.png".